Getting The Wrong Status Codes From HTTP Client Requests
I wrote a simple windows forms application that helps me test HTTP status codes. I've been having an issue where I'm getting bogus status codes from HTTPClient request though.  Code below:
private async void CheckStatusButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> urlsToCheck = URLs.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
    List<string> statusCodeResults = new List<string>();


    foreach (string item in urlsToCheck)
    {
        using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                {
                    NoCache = true
                };

                try
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(item))
                    {



                        if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == string.Empty)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200)
                        {

                        }

                        if ((int)response.StatusCode == 404)
                        {

                        }


                        if ((int)response.StatusCode == 301)
                        {

                        }


                        statusCodeResults.Add(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    statusCodeResults.Add("999" + item.ToString());
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    foreach (var item in statusCodeResults)
    {
        statusCodes.AppendText(item + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

The issue I'm having is that I keep getting the wrong status codes and variable status codes from URLs.  I will run a batch of URLs to check and get 200 statuses on URLs that should be 404ing, but when I test them as a single URL I get the correct status code. If I run the same batch of URLs 10x, it's a different pool of ones that 404 vs 200 each time.  They should all be 404s every time.  I'm using a batch of URLs for a WordPress site and when I use a tool like https://httpstatus.io/ I correctly get a list of 404s.  I have some other cases where I'm getting the wrong status codes outside of this so in general I am not trusting the results of making these HTTP requests and responses but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that would be giving me these results.

Note I have tried setting AllowAutoRedirect to both true and false

I have also tried disposing the handler/client/response at appropriate points in the loop

I don't know but you shouldn't create so many HttpClient and HttpClientHandlers. They are thread-safe, just keep one static one.

As mentioned, use a (one) static HttpClient, with a SocketsHttpHandler (plus the configuration and the Headers), similar to what is shown in the first snippet here (you don't need the Lazy<T> stuff for what you're doing here, but it doesn't hurt either) -- Yes, I'm suggesting you test this with .NET 8+

Be aware that it is possible for a "404 page" to return a 200 OK status code and conversely for an fully functional web page to return e.g. 404 Not Found. Unless you have already done so, I would recommend testing the same requests using e.g. Postman to see what HTTP status codes are present in the responses.
